# Rails-tutorial rails not working but puma -w0 is working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma, ruby-on-rails-5

Rails is not working, but when I run `puma -w0` it works. I am facing this problem after completing Chapter 7 of ruby on rails tutorial book.

[image: rails s not working]    [image: puma -w0 is working]

Comment: Rails development on Windows sucks. Hard. Dual-boot with Linux or prepare for a lifetime of dealing with impossible bugs

Comment: Is there any way to fix it in windows 8?

Comment: Short answer: no. Longer answer: It will be so taxing/time consuming to figure that out, and it will probably be the first of many bugs you'll face with windows RoR development, that you'll never get anything real done. Dual boot with [Linux Ubuntu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1uVcsFhv2Vo). Also not to be Microsoft fanboy but you should really upgrade to Windows 10. Windows 8 is less supported than Windows 7 at this point so you will get almost no help with any OS issues you have.

Comment: Please do not include screenshots of code, error messages, or other text. Please [edit] your question to include these as text.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.